# How to create Autocomplete textview drop down with circular radius in Android?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, textview

How can we create autocomplete textview dropdown list with corner radius as i have attach one image that what i actually wants ... if anyone know please help me.[image: i want actually like this...]

Comment: Please , add your code that you have tried!!!

Comment: You can create custom view with list and custom background

Comment: @HinaKhuman i think you get !dea what i actually wants so you can try :)

Comment: try to create editext with PopupMenu with list.

Answer (score 4):

Try below code:

```
edtAutocompleteTextview.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rouned_corner_black_bg_track));
```

**rouned_corner_black_bg_track.xml**

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<corners
    android:radius="20dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#000000" />
```

Comment: From the Docs `android:popupBackground` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView#attr_android:popupBackground

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add custom adapter for your drop down and set layout for that so you can archive the required output.

i think this one helpful for u :d

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/04/custom-spinner-with-different-normal.html

https://www.android-examples.com/change-spinner-text-color-in-android-programmatically/

Comment: i have tried that both way but background come simple with corner not come with redius corner :(